# What is 殺虫剤たいたら?

Tags: grammar, translation, manga

I have problem understanding the following sentence from the lower right panel:

> そう思{おも}ってあわてて殺虫剤{さっちゅうざい}**たいたら**私{わたし}がいられなくなって

殺虫剤 is pesticide, but I don't know how to parse たいたら. My bad guess is that it's a conjugation of　たく but I can't go further. There is no たく that seems to make sense in this context.

Another question is 私がいられなくなって --- I'm not quite sure how to translate this. "I can't be here"?

[image: OL Shinkaron]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The verb here is 「焚{た}く」 meaning "to burn" as in "to burn incense".　The kind of insecticide we are talking about actually diffuses a ton of smoke.

Watch this short video and you will know exactly why you could not stay in your house for at least a few hours after setting off some types of 殺虫剤{さっちゅうざい}.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nDXTyB6MW8

Luckily, the video title contains our verb in question -- 「バルサンを焚{た}いてみました。」.  バルサン is the name of the insecticide.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I had never seen this type of pesticide before.

Answer (score 0):

"[焚]{た}く" means to burn, make a fire, like kindle firewood and coal. "[炊]{た}く" means to boil, like boil water in the boiler, or cook, like cook rice.

Actually you cannot burn insecticides such as being sold by the name of Barusan - a rat mite-cite. But when you add water to Barusan up to the designated line inside the container, it erupts white gas like a smoke screen as if something burning.

“いられなくなって” means “I cannot stay there.” If you set up Barusan in your living room or bedroom and once it starts to smolder, you got to rush out of the room, otherwise you’ll be choked.

Please note that "[焚]{た}く"and "炊{た}く" are different words, though phonetically sound the same.